# Vertical alignment misunderstanding

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with next code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .circle {
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

        .circle.red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .circle.green {
            background-color: green;
        }

        .circle.blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .some_class {
            height: 24px;
            width: 320px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            background: yellow;
        }

        .some_class div {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: aqua;
        }

        .some_class .circle {
            margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;;
        }

        .some_class .title {
            background-color: blueviolet;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="some_id" class="some_class">
        <div class="circle green">

        </div>
        <div class="title">
            Some title
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            Some text
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem here is that "Some title" and "Some text" blocks are shown below the center of the green circle. Moreover these blocks are not even lying inside of `<div id="some_id">`. 
How can I fix it? It would be great if I can vertically align these divs to the middle of the main div. But at least I want them to locate inside of that div.
I can do something like this:

```
.some_class .title {
            background-color: blueviolet;
            position: relative;
            top: -7px;
        }
```

but it dosn't seem to be right, 'cause I still can't understand why they are out of main div.

Comment: Could you set up a JSFiddle for us to, well, fiddle with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your 3 child-div's are set to `display: inline-block`, their default `vertical-align` property is set to `baseline` which is why they aren't vertically aligned. You will need to add `vertical-align: middle` to all your 3 child-div's like this:

```
.text, .title, .circle {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4m98zdvy/1/)**.

```css
.circle {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.circle.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.circle.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.circle.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.some_class {
  height: 24px;
  width: 320px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}
.some_class div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.some_class .circle {
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  ;
}
.some_class .title {
  background-color: blueviolet;
}
.text,
.title,
.circle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="some_id" class="some_class">
  <div class="circle green"></div>
  <div class="title">Some title</div>
  <div class="text">Some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For default `vertical-align` is `baseline` the base of the text taken as reference. Just change that property:

```
.some_class div {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle; /*ADD THIS LINE*/
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Check this **[DemoFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phkxjs2z/)**